# RKHunter and CHKRootkit Warns About /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/.path

Tags: audit

In relation to [my previous question.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48526/rk-hunter-warns-about-usr-lib-apache2-mpm-event-apache2-uses-deleted-files-how/) I have this Warning again from both RKHunter and Chkrootkit.

My VPS has been turned off for how many weeks, until I turned it on again to deploy my website. After the deployment, I did the RKhunter Scan and Chkrootkit and it warned me about;

using `Chkrootkit`...

The following suspicious files and directories were found: 
`/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/.path`

While in RKhunter...

Warned about deleted files being used in... 
`/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/.path`

I am exactly clueless on how to deal with the issue.

**Is this False Positive? Will I just add it to the white list?**

Comment: Are there places where the warnings are explained fully?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably false positive (depends of its content). Got the same warning on two different clean machines (Ubuntu 12.04 & Debian 7).